# Should I be taking the partial derivative or the total derivative?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, partial-derivative

Say I have the following relationship
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = y$$
where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, such that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.  The function $f$ is Legendre Type, such that I can take its legendre transfrom (convex conjugate) and also yield the following relationship
$$
g(y) = f^{\ast}(y)
$$
So, in that first expression, in taking the derivative, I am finding the argument of the convex conjugate.

I now construct $f$ as a linear combination of basis functions, as follows

$$
f(a_1,\cdots,a_n,x) =\sum_ia_if_i(x) 
$$
where $a_i ,x \in \mathbb{R}\;\forall i$ such that we now have $f:\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f_i:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.  Continuing with the Legendre transform relationships, where all $f_i$ are strictly convex and Legendre type, I therefore have
$$
g(a_1,\cdots,a_n,y) = \sum_ia_if^{\ast}\left(\frac{y_i}{a_i}\right)
$$

Again, I want to find $y$.  I am not sure if I should be taking the partial derivative with respect to $x$, holding all $a_i$ constant, or the total derivative with respect to $x$.

In other words, which of these is correct?
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(a_i,\cdots,a_n,x) = \sum_ia_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f_i(x) = y
$$
or
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}f(a_i,\cdots,a_n,x) &= \sum_ia_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f_i(x)\; + \;\sum_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial a_i}\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial x} \\
&=\sum_ia_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f_i(x)\; + \;\sum_if_i(x)\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial x}\\
&= y
\end{align}

Or perhaps neither?

Prompted by a comment, I should note that (at least some) $\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial x}$ are non-zero, so the two approaches are not equivalent.

Comment: Is $\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial x}$ nonzero?

Comment: yes - I shall add details to the question to clarify.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you specify what $x$ is (it seems as $x$ is just one real variable) but what is $f$? If $f:\mathbb R^{n+1}\to\mathbb R$ then $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n,x)\mapsto f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n,x)$, but you seem to look for something like
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(x_1(x),x_2(x),\ldots, x_n(x),x)
$$
which is different from $\partial_xf(x_1(x),x_2(x),\ldots,x_n(x),x)$ in general.

Comment: I have clarified.  If I understand, you are suggesting the total derivative then?

Comment: Since you say that $\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial x}$ is nonzero in general, the two approaches are indeed non-equivalent. The question is more what you are asked to find. I think you are asked about the total derivative because of the symbol that is used.

Comment: Hmm, okay, I tried to keep the question as general as possible, but I shall add some more context which I hope will clarify exactly what I am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In calculating the form for g

$$
g(a_1,\cdots,a_n,y) = \sum_ia_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f_i(x) = y
$$

we hold the values of the variables $a_i$ constant, so it makes sense to do so in the derivative too.

Therefore, I think its sensible to take the partial derivative, holding $a_i$ constant.
This is also fairly simple to show numerically/empirically for a few choice examples.